# In Rails 3 how can I select items where the items.join_model.id != x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, conditional-statements, arel

In my Rails models I have:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flags
  has_many :accounts, :through => :flags
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flags
  has_many :songs, :through => :flags
end

class Flag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :account
end
```

I'm looking for a way to create a scope in the Song model that fetches songs that DO NOT have a given account associated with it.

I've tried:

```
Song.joins(:accounts).where('account_id != ?', @an_account)
```

but it returns an empty set. This might be because there are songs that have no accounts attached to it? I'm not sure, but really struggling with this one.

**Update**

The result set I'm looking for includes songs that do not have a given account associated with it. This includes songs that have no flags.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Can you post the SQL output of **Song.joins(:accounts).where('account_id == ?', @an_account)**

Comment: I pasted the wrong code into my question. It should have been !=. However, here is the SQL output: `SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" INNER JOIN "flags" ON "songs"."id" = "flags"."song_id" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "flags"."account_id" WHERE (account_id != 1) ORDER BY genre ASC, title ASC`

Comment: Can you try replacing joins(:accounts) with includes(:accounts)?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: account_id: SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" WHERE (account_id != 1) ORDER BY genre ASC, title ASC` Looks like its looking for an account_id column in the songs table, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I understanding your question correctly - you want Songs that are not associated with a particular account?

Try:

```
Song.joins(:accounts).where(Account.arel_table[:id].not_eq(@an_account.id))
```

**Answer revised:** (in response to clarification in the comments)

You probably want SQL conditions like this:

```
Song.all(:conditions =>
  ["songs.id NOT IN (SELECT f.song_id FROM flags f WHERE f.account_id = ?)", @an_account.id]
)
```

Or in ARel, you could get the same SQL generated like this:

```
songs = Song.arel_table
flags = Flag.arel_table

Song.where(songs[:id].not_in(
  flags.project(:song_id).where(flags[:account_id].eq(@an_account.id))
))
```

I generally prefer ARel, and I prefer it in this case too.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that's correct. When an account flags a song I don't want that song selected for the account that flagged it. I ran your query and received the same empty set as mine. Here is the SQL output: `SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" INNER JOIN "flags" ON "songs"."id" = "flags"."song_id" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "flags"."account_id" WHERE ("accounts"."id" != 1) ORDER BY genre ASC, title ASC`

Comment: @jklina - The SQL looks correct. Are your raw data associations in your database correct? I mean, an empty result set could be considered correct if there are no flags associated with that particular account. This probably sounds like a stupid question, but these things do happen. The query looks like it would work to me, if the database was in the correct state. Check your data's foreign key relations in the DB

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, but that's what I'm looking for - a result set without a given account associated with it whether it has another account or no accounts.

Comment: Ahh... I see the problem now. Because of the join through 'flags' you are running into a "three-valued logic" problem. I have revised my answer. I tried to do it here in the comments, but it lacked clarity. Sorry about the delay in responding - I had to go to bed.

Comment: No worries at all. I eventually wound up with the SQL, but the ARel is much better. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If your where clause is not a typo, it is incorrect. Code frequently uses `==` for equality, but sql does not, use a single equals sign as such:

```
Song.joins(:accounts).where('account_id = ?', @an_account.id)
```

**Edit:**

Actually there is a way to use activerecord to do this for you, instead of writing your own bound sql fragments:

```
Song.joins(:accounts).where(:accounts => {:id => @an_account.id})
```

Comment: I'm sorry I pasted the wrong code. I was testing if it worked with ==. It should be !=. I updated my question.